# SnappyData - Error creating Kafka streaming table

Tags: sql, snappydata

I'm seeing an issue when creating a spark streaming table using kafka from the snappy shell.

**'The exception 'Invalid input 'C', expected dmlOperation, insert, withIdentifier, select or put (line 1, column 1):'**

Reference: http://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/streamingWithSQL/#spark-streaming-overview

Here is my sql:

```
CREATE STREAM TABLE if not exists sensor_data_stream 
(sensor_id string, metric string)
using kafka_stream 
options (
    storagelevel 'MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2',
    rowConverter 'io.snappydata.app.streaming.KafkaStreamToRowsConverter',
    zkQuorum 'localhost:2181',
    groupId 'streamConsumer',
    topics 'test:01');
```

The shell seems to not like the script at the first character 'C'.  I'm attempting to execute the script using the following command:

```
snappy> run '/scripts/my_test_sensor_script.sql';
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: Hi Mike, will get this answered for you ASAP

Answer (score 3):

There is some inconsistency in documentation and actual syntax.The correct syntax is:

```
CREATE STREAM TABLE sensor_data_stream if not exists (sensor_id string, 
metric string) using kafka_stream 
options (storagelevel 'MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2', 
rowConverter 'io.snappydata.app.streaming.KafkaStreamToRowsConverter', 
zkQuorum 'localhost:2181',
 groupId 'streamConsumer',  topics 'test:01');
```

One more thing you need to do is to write row converter for your data

Comment: Thank you Sachin!  the updated syntax worked.  As expected based on your comment about writing a row converter, I'm getting a ClassNotFound exception on io.snappydata.app.streaming.KafkaStreamToRowsConverter.  I will search the documentation to work through that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Mike, You need to create your own rowConverter class by implementing following trait -

```
trait StreamToRowsConverter extends Serializable {
  def toRows(message: Any): Seq[Row]
}
```

and then specify that rowConverter fully qualified class name in the DDL. 
The rowConverter is specific to a schema. 
'io.snappydata.app.streaming.KafkaStreamToRowsConverter' is just an placeholder class name, which should be replaced by your own rowConverter class.

Comment: Thanks Yogesh.  I'm attempting to convert a Java Object that I send to Kafka.  I'm trying to understand how to convert this object using the row converter.  Is there any documentation that you would recommend that explains this process?